# netstat not display open ports but I can telnet to the open port

Tags: linux, networking, netstat

The ports isn't being display when I run netstat

```
 netstat -nal | grep 2237
```

tcping does show that the port is open

```
C:\Users\slee>tcping 172.29.69.250 2237
Probing 172.29.69.250:2237/tcp - Port is open - time=17.483ms
Probing 172.29.69.250:2237/tcp - Port is open - time=16.420ms
```

There quite a number of network aliases (69 of them) on this server:

```
eth4
eth4:1 
eth4:2   
...
eth4:69
```

Comment: If the destination is DNAT-ed and routed, then the host won't have this socket resource itself, just as a router. This can happen for example when there is VM or container technology running.

Comment: I did an ifconfig and there is no network aliases for 172.29.69.250 and iptables has no rules. I did a `yum list installed` and grep for `docker` and `lxc` but nothing appeared. Where would this IP be on this system? It is a CentOS 6 server.

Comment: That was a comment due to lack of information. With what you added in this comment, you can forget my former comment, that's not it.

Comment: The `netstat` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) states that the utility is obsolete and one should use `ss` instead.

Answer (score 1):

use -t option for TCP ports as described by Geek above
or you can use ss utilty

```
ss -ltnu | grep -i 2237
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily [get all the ip addresses](https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/check-ip-address-in-linux) of you box with ip addr or ifconfig command in Linux.

If you can not get that ip address in your box, that means it might use some other technology. It is out of your server. You can not find it on your server.

There are different ways which get this like network NAT on firewall, server virtualization etc.

You can run dmidecode command to check which virtualization your server is using.

For example, in openstack, you can add a public ip address from openstack console. You can login this server with this public ip address with ssh but when you run ip addr command in server, you can only see a private ip address.

I think it might be your case.

but there should be a connection between local and your server. The port might be different with this port.

Comment: The question was about finding open ports and the commands given show the OP knows the IP address of the server. I don't see how this answer contributes to the question asked.

Comment: we need check why the ip address was not running on the server side first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you used netstat -tlnp | grep -i "port_no".

t- TCP
l- listening
p- port
n- not listening.

Comment: The `netstat` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) states that the utility is obsolete and one should use `ss` instead. The equivalent command when using `ss` has already been given as an answer.